# Nexus 4 Ubuntu Android Dual Boot

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, software-installation, ubuntu-touch, android

I was able to successfully install the Ubuntu Dual Boot app on my Nexus 4. During installation of Ubuntu on the phone the following error was returned in the console.

```
"Script execution exception write failed: EPIPE"
(Broken Pipe)
```

I tried three different channels with the same result. Any idea what I could be missing ? Here is the full log from the installation attempt.

```
Device: google/occam/mako:5.1.1/LMY48M/2167285:user/release-keys
APK Version: 1.0.0

Starting download
Downloading: ubuntu-d8d097dfc125dc91455594656762421ba6ac8fbf19524bfa07db1a879d0adee1.tar.xz
Checksum Verifying: ubuntu-d8d097dfc125dc91455594656762421ba6ac8fbf19524bfa07db1a879d0adee1.tar.xz
Checksum Verified: ubuntu-d8d097dfc125dc91455594656762421ba6ac8fbf19524bfa07db1a879d0adee1.tar.xz
Downloading: device-ed6a4ed78cc7b5bd78815514cd3bb93c852f6593e0df66304f6e720684e11dc3.tar.xz
Checksum Verifying: device-ed6a4ed78cc7b5bd78815514cd3bb93c852f6593e0df66304f6e720684e11dc3.tar.xz
Checksum Verified: device-ed6a4ed78cc7b5bd78815514cd3bb93c852f6593e0df66304f6e720684e11dc3.tar.xz
Downloading: custom-1f38c6806760389f4f66cdb3702d454d8d1b9611f2220e0594311ad0ffc17650.tar.xz
Checksum Verifying: custom-1f38c6806760389f4f66cdb3702d454d8d1b9611f2220e0594311ad0ffc17650.tar.xz
Checksum Verified: custom-1f38c6806760389f4f66cdb3702d454d8d1b9611f2220e0594311ad0ffc17650.tar.xz
Downloading: version-63.tar.xz
Checksum Verifying: version-63.tar.xz
Checksum Verified: version-63.tar.xz
Generating update command
Download done in 525 seconds
Starting update script - /data/data/com.canonical.ubuntu.installer/files/ubuntu_release/update_command
Extracting supporting files at /data/data/com.canonical.ubuntu.installer/files/uTemp
Script execution exception write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. The SuperSU app was not installed properly so the phone was not properly rooted. I used another app to root the device and the installation went successfully.